# Form with nested resource: can't keep the association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a problem with a form with nested resource. The data model is easy:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :finders]
  has_many :event_contents
end

class EventContent < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
end
```

My form:

```
= simple_form_for([:admin, @event, @event.event_contents.new], remote: true) do |f|
  .chat-form
    .input-cont
      = f.input :content, label: false, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }    
    .btn-cont
      %span.arrow
      = f.submit 'invia', class: 'btn blue icn-only'
```

The controller:

```
class Admin::EventContentsController < AdminController
  def create
    @event_content = EventContent.new event_content_params
    @event_content.user_id = current_user.id if current_user
    if @event_content.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js { render :nothing => true }
      end
    else

    end
  end

  private
  def event_content_params
    params.require(:event_content).permit(
      :content,
      :event_id,
      :user_id
      )
  end
end
```

When i submit the post in the params instead of event_id I have the event "slug"

```
pry(#<Admin::EventContentsController>)> params
=> {"utf8"=>"✓", "event_content"=>{"content"=>"uhm"}, "commit"=>"invia", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"admin/event_contents", "event_id"=>"test-test-test"}
```

The record is created in the db, but event_id is nil so the association is broken.
Why instead of the event_id I have the event slug???

**Update**

The issue was the controller:

```
def create
    @event = Event.find params[:event_id]
    @event_content = @event.event_contents.build event_content_params
    @event_content.user_id = current_user.id if current_user
    if @event_content.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
      end
    else

    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try doing the following:

1. in your Event model add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :event_contents`
2. in your form, when you are collecting the :event_contents replace

   ```
   f.input :content, label: false, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }
   ```

   with the following:

   ```
   f.fields_for :event_contents do |content|
   content.input :content
   end
   ```
3. update your strong params in your *Events* controller to include {:event_contents_attributes} which might look something like below depending on the other params you need to pass through:

   ```
   params.require(:event).permit(:name, {:event_contents_attributes => [:content]})
   ```
4. In your Events controller, update `def new` to include this line item `event_content = @event.event_contents.build`

All that to say, I believe you would want this to be routed to your Events controller and not your EventContents controller because the :event_contents are nested in the :event.  It looks like your form is submitting to the EventContents controller currently. Also, I don't believe this argument in your simple_form_for `@event.event_contents.new` is necessary.

Here's what I built off of your question.  It's not admin namespaced but might be helpful.

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController


 def new
    @event = Event.new
    event_content = @event.event_contents.build
  end

def create
    @event = Event.new(event_params)
    respond_to do |format|
        if @event.save
            format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @event }
            format.js
        else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end
private
 def event_params
      params.require(:event).permit(:name, {:event_contents_attributes => [:content]})
    end
end
```

Event model:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :event_contents
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :event_contents
end
```

And finally the form:

```
<%= form_for(@event) do |event| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= event.label :name %><br>
    <%= event.text_field :name %>
  </div>

    <%= event.fields_for :event_contents do |content| %>
        <div class="field">
        <%= content.label :content %>
        <%= content.text_field :content %>
    </div>
    <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= event.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```